Does Kabbalah really teach this?
Israel Shahak in his book Jewish History, Jewish Religion: the Weight of Three Thousand Years claims that the majority of Orthodox Jews believe the following quotation.  He does not give sources for any of these claims.  Is this actually true?  Is this only believed by Hasidic Jews?  Is this what it says in the Zohar?  If there are Jews who believe this, is it condemned by others?

According to the Kabbalah, the universe is ruled not by one god but by several deities of various characters and influences emanated by a dim, distant First Cause.  Omitting many details, one can summarize the system as follows.  From the First Cause, first a male god called ‘Wisdom’ or ‘Father’ and then a female goddess called ‘Knowledge’ or ‘Mother’ were emanated or born.  From the marriage of these two, a pair of younger gods were born: Son, also called by many other names such as ‘Small Face’ or ‘The Holy Blessed One’; and Daughter, also called ‘Lady’ (or ‘Matronit’, a word derived from Latin), ‘Shekhinah,’ ‘Queen’, and so on.  These two younger gods should be united, but their union is prevented by the machinations of Satan, who in this system is a very important and independent personage.  The Creation was undertaken by the First Cause in order to allow them to unite, but because of the Fall they became more disunited than ever, and indeed Satan has managed to come very close to the divine Daughter and even to rape her (either seemingly or in fact– opinions differ on this).  The creation of the Jewish people was undertaken in order to mend the break caused by Adam and Eve, and under Mount Sinai this was for a moment achieved: the male god Son, incarnated in Moses, was united with the goddess Shekhinah.  Unfortunately, the sin of the golden calf again caused disunity in the godhead; but the repentance of the Jewish people has mended matters to some extent.  Similarly, each incident of biblical Jewish history is believed to be associated with the union or disunion of the divine pair.  The Jewish conquest of Palestine from the Canaanites and the building of the first and second Temple are particularly propitious for their union, while the destruction of the Temples and exile of the Jews from the Holy Land are merely external signs not only of the divine disunion but also of a real ‘whoring after strange gods’: Daughter falls closely into the power of Satan, while Son takes various female satanic personages to his bed instead of his proper wife.  The duty of pious Jews is to restore through their prayers and religious acts the perfect divine unity, in the form of sexual union, between the male and female deities.  Thus before most ritual acts, which every devout Jew has to perform many times each day, the following Kabbalistic formula is recited: ‘For the sake of the [sexual] congress of the Holy Blessed One and his Shekhinah.’


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Just wiki him. You'll get all your answers.

Nope. Absolutely not. Shahak lied. Just blatantly. I don’t even think he misunderstood, I think he just lied. It’s so inane, so crazy, so baseless, that I don’t think there’s any other explanation.

Reductionism is the ultimate form of sarcasm.
Sarcasm is a subset of cynicism and is forbidden and very dangerous for one's soul, because it makes light of the holy, and that has a powerfully influential psychological effect in putting people off the idea, that is almost impossible to withstand, and thus they lose touch with truth and holiness*. One shouldn't really even read the above at all.**
Some of the above is reductionism of parables given in authentic sources. Some of it is foreign completely. All of the conjectures and conclusions that are made are incorrect.
The Tzemach Tzedek explains in Derech Mitzvotecha He'Emanut Elokut 5, that this type of reductionism is a misunderstanding (at best):

שֶׁאֵין הַכַּוָּנָה שֶׁהַכֵּלִים פּוֹעֲלִים בְּעַצְמָן חַס וְשָׁלוֹם
כְּפִי שֶׁנִּרְאֶה מִשִּׁטְחִיּוּת לְשׁוֹן
The point about the Sefirot is not that they work independantly [of
Hashem], chas veshalom, according to a superficial appearance of
the wording [used in Kabbalistic parables]

tl;dr: NO!

* Rabbi Aharon Zacai Shlita writes in Habayit HaYehudi 7:29, p 246, quoting Mesilat Yisharim Ch. 5:
When one becomes accustomed to mockery, they lose the ability to be inspired by words of wisdom and rebuke, and even the best of teachings will not penetrate their heart. Thus, such people have no place among those who engage in spiritual growth and Torah study. They are likened to a sealed vessel that cannot absorb anything.
** Ibid, p 248:
It is forbidden to read books filled with foolishness, idle chatter, and inappropriate jokes, as well as anything that promotes cynicism. This is included in the verse, "Do not turn to worthless things" (Vayikra 19:4), which means avoiding things that have no spiritual value. Even in matters of humor, one should refrain from engaging in improper jokes or reading material that includes immoral or degrading content. This is particularly relevant to books written by scoffers and those that mock Torah and mitzvot.
See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 307:16 and the commentaries of the Magen Avraham ד״ה משום מושב לצים, Beur Halacha ד״ה מחטיאים את הרבים, and Mishna Berura ס״ק ס״א

מִשִּׁטְחִיּוּת - a pretty good word for "reductionistic"

The claim:

The universe is ruled not by one god but by several deities of various characters

That line contradicts three of the first 13 principles of our faith, as redacted in the Ani Ma'Amin's and summarized by the Yigdal prayer.

אֲנִי מַאֲמִין בֶּאֱמוּנָה שְׁלֵמָה, שֶׁהַבּוֹרֵא יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ הוּא בּוֹרֵא וּמַנְהִיג לְכָל הַבְּרוּאִים, וְהוּא לְבַדּו עָשָׂה וְעוֹשֶׂה וְיַעֲשֶׂה לְכָל הַמַּעֲשִׂים. ‏


To believe that the Creator created and runs the world and its creatures, and He, Himself, by Himself alone did, does and will continue to make everything happen.


אֲנִי מַאֲמִין בֶּאֱמוּנָה שְׁלֵמָה, שֶׁהַבּוֹרֵא יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ הוּא יָחִיד וְאֵין יְחִידוּת כָּמוֹהוּ בְּשׁוּם פָּנִים, וְהוּא לְבַדּוֹ אֱלֹהֵינוּ, הָיָה הוֶה וְיִהְיֶה. ‏


To believe that the Creator is unique, nothing compares to His Uniqueness and He Himself, by Himself, is The Power Behind Everything (a.k.a. Gcd), who always, was, is, and will be.


אֲנִי מַאֲמִין בֶּאֱמוּנָה שְׁלֵמָה, שֶׁהַבּוֹרֵא יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ אֵינוֹ גוּף, וְלֹא יַשִּׂיגוּהוּ מַשִּׂיגֵי הַגּוּף, וְאֵין לוֹ שׁוּם דִּמְיוֹן כְּלָל.‏


To believe that The Creator has no physical aspects to Him, is impossible to describe using physical terminology, and has no similarity to anything else in existence.

That's what all Orthodox Jews believe, including Hasidim.
The first line is false.
The rest is not worth reading. It is full of nonsense from that first line to the word in brackets on the last line.

I will answer your question as to whether Jews believe this not by using a source, but by means of giving you a counterexample.
I could very easily write:
According to Christians, the universe is not ruled by one god but by a zombie Jew who definitely didn't die but disappeared a few thousands years ago. This Zombie still appears to Christians and they strengthen their belief in him by opposing abortion laws and eating Pigs on their Zombie God's December birthday, etc etc.
Everything I said above is technically true for American Christianity but no Christian would agree that I've represented their beliefs honestly or even cogently. The same is true of what you quoted. Sure on the surface this person knows the big strokes of the pen regarding Kabbalah, but what he chose to write about it is basically nonsenical.
Just like no Christian would say their God is a Jewish Zombie, I doubt any Kabbalist would agree with even the starting premise of "the universe is ruled not by one god but by several deities of various characters and influences emanated by a dim, distant First Cause". Most kaballistic Jews who had a good Jewish foundation before studying Kabbalah would die on the hill of Hear O Israel, the LORD is our God, the Lord is One/Alone.
Note: My description of Christianity should be taken as a satirical parody, not my personal view or Judaism's view on Christianity. It is not intended to denigrate Christianity or its followers.

You've given the most cogent description of the religion based around that man I've seen in some time. Chazak u baruch, @Aaron!

I'm sorry but I must refuse your compliment. While I am not Christian, and have very many reasons for not being Christian. This post was meant to be satire. There are many Christians in my life whose religion and relationship with God I respect. I ask that anyone who reads this post not consider it my opinion about Christianity.

For the record, it is my opinion. Sure, there are religious lines of reasoning that connect the ideas, but that doesn’t somehow give them coherence. The whole premise of Christianity is faulty.

@QwertyCTRL. I find the "orthodox" premises of Judaism, Christianity, and Islam to be faulty. A lot of people make fun of Mormons for believing "crazy" things like they will become like Gods in control of planets. As if somehow that's crazier than believing the creator of the universe cares if I cut my newborn son's penis or not.

@Aaron a flat earther, if he doesn't accept the truth of spherical earth theorem, can also "find the things that the spherical-earth weirdoes claim to be 'crazy'". That's not a proof of anything, even if it is a righteous heart that feels this way in order to maintain one's love and respect for all people, even flat earthers (which of course we should, which is not contradicted by explaining that they are wrong about something).

The short answer to your question is no, "kabbalah" does not teach this and it is not actually true.
Nor do "Hasidic Jews" believe this and it does not accurately portray what is written in the Zohar.
For more details and a discussion of your closing question, see the "Move to chat" link from Isaac Moses in the comments under the question.

While Shahak’s text uses actual translations of certain kabbalistic concepts, it gives interpretations that are entirely false.
For example, despite the appearance of the Satan in a dialogue in the book of Job, Chazal are clear that all events are ultimately blessings, no matter how obscure the cause may be.
Berakhot 60b

חַיָּיב אָדָם לְבָרֵךְ כּוּ׳: מַאי ״חַיָּיב לְבָרֵךְ עַל הָרָעָה
כְּשֵׁם שֶׁמְּבָרֵךְ עַל הַטּוֹבָה״? אִילֵּימָא כְּשֵׁם שֶׁמְּבָרֵךְ
עַל הַטּוֹבָה ״הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב״, כָּךְ מְבָרֵךְ עַל הָרָעָה
״הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב״, וְהָתְנַן עַל בְּשׂוֹרוֹת טוֹבוֹת אוֹמֵר
״הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב״, עַל בְּשׂוֹרוֹת רָעוֹת אוֹמֵר ״בָּרוּךְ …
דַּיַּין הָאֱמֶת״! אָמַר רָבָא: לֹא נִצְרְכָה, אֶלָּא לְקַבּוֹלִינְהוּ
בְּשִׂמְחָה.
We learned in the mishna: One is obligated to recite a blessing for
the bad that befalls him just as he recites a blessing for the good
that befalls him. The Gemara asks: What does it mean: One is obligated
to recite a blessing for the bad just as for the good? If we say this
means that just as one recites a blessing for a positive event with
the formula: Who is good and does good, so too one recites a blessing
for a calamity with the formula: Who is good and does good, didn’t we
learn in our mishna that over good tidings one recites: Who is good
and does good, while over bad tidings one recites: Blessed…the true
Judge? Rather, Rava said: The mishna’s statement was only necessary to
instruct us to accept bad tidings with the same joy with which we
accept good tidings, not to instruct with regard to which blessing to
recite.

Yad HaChazakah, Blessings 10

שָׁמַע שְׁמוּעָה טוֹבָה מְבָרֵךְ בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ׳‎ אֱלֹהֵינוּ
מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב. שָׁמַע שְׁמוּעָה רָעָה מְבָרֵךְ
בָּרוּךְ דַּיַּן הָאֱמֶת. וְחַיָּב אָדָם לְבָרֵךְ עַל הָרָעָה בְּטוּב
נֶפֶשׁ כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁמְּבָרֵךְ עַל הַטּוֹבָה בְּשִׂמְחָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר
(דברים ו ה) ״וְאָהַבְתָּ אֵת יְיָ׳‎ אֱלֹהֶיךָ״ וְגוֹ׳‎ (דברים ו ה)
״וּבְכָל מְאֹדֶךָ״. וּבִכְלַל אַהֲבָה הַיְתֵרָה שֶׁנִּצְטַוֵּינוּ
בָּהּ שֶׁאֲפִלּוּ בְּעֵת שֶׁיָּצֵר לוֹ יוֹדֶה וִישַׁבֵּחַ בְּשִׂמְחָה:
When a person hears favorable tidings, he should recite the blessing:
"Blessed are You, God, our Lord, King of the universe, who is good and
does good." If he hears bad tidings, he should recite the blessing:
"Blessed [are You...] the true Judge."A person is obligated to recite
a blessing over undesirable occurrences with a positive spirit, in the
same manner as he joyfully recites a blessing over desirable
occurrences. [This is implied by Deuteronomy 6:5]: "And you shall love
God, your Lord... with all your might." Included in this extra
dimension of love that we were commanded [to express] is to
acknowledge and praise [God] with happiness even at one's time of
difficulty.

Menachot 29b

אמר רב יהודה אמר רב בשעה שעלה משה למרום מצאו להקב"ה שיושב וקושר כתרים
לאותיות אמר לפניו רבש"ע מי מעכב על ידך אמר לו אדם אחד יש שעתיד להיות
בסוף כמה דורות ועקיבא בן יוסף שמו שעתיד לדרוש על כל קוץ וקוץ תילין
תילין של הלכות אמר לפניו רבש"ע הראהו לי אמר לו חזור לאחורך הלך וישב
בסוף שמונה שורות ולא היה יודע מה הן אומרים תשש כחו כיון שהגיע לדבר אחד
אמרו לו תלמידיו רבי מנין לך אמר להן הלכה למשה מסיני נתיישבה דעתו חזר
ובא לפני הקב"ה אמר לפניו רבונו של עולם יש לך אדם כזה ואתה נותן תורה
ע"י אמר לו שתוק כך עלה במחשבה לפני אמר לפניו רבונו של עולם הראיתני
תורתו הראני שכרו אמר לו חזור [לאחורך] חזר לאחוריו ראה ששוקלין בשרו
במקולין אמר לפניו רבש"ע זו תורה וזו שכרה א"ל שתוק כך עלה במחשבה לפני
§ Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: When Moses ascended on High, he found
the Holy One, Blessed be He, sitting and tying crowns on the letters
of the Torah. Moses said before God: Master of the Universe, who is
preventing You from giving the Torah without these additions? God said
to him: There is a man who is destined to be born after several
generations, and Akiva ben Yosef is his name; he is destined to derive
from each and every thorn of these crowns mounds upon mounds of
halakhot. It is for his sake that the crowns must be added to the
letters of the Torah. Moses said before God: Master of the Universe,
show him to me. God said to him: Return behind you. Moses went and sat
at the end of the eighth row in Rabbi Akiva’s study hall and did not
understand what they were saying. Moses’ strength waned. When Rabbi
Akiva arrived at the discussion of one matter, his students said to
him: My teacher, from where do you derive this? Rabbi Akiva said to
them: It is a halakha transmitted to Moses from Sinai. When Moses
heard this, his mind was put at ease. Moses returned and came before
the Holy One, Blessed be He, and said before Him: Master of the
Universe, You have a man as great as this and yet You still choose to
give the Torah through me. Why? God said to him: Be silent; this
intention arose before Me. Moses said before God: Master of the
Universe, You have shown me Rabbi Akiva’s Torah, now show me his
reward. God said to him: Return to where you were. Moses went back and
saw that they were weighing Rabbi Akiva’s flesh in a butcher shop
[bemakkulin], as Rabbi Akiva was tortured to death by the Romans.
Moses said before Him: Master of the Universe, this is Torah and this
is its reward? God said to him: Be silent; this intention arose before
Me.

The logic is that even when events conspire to appear to make a person a “victim” of circumstance or chance, there is a divine meaning that may exceed our understanding.
